# grouping items on kendo-angular dropdownlist

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

How can I group the items to display in a `kendo-dropdownlist`? I've been trying to combine it with `groupBy` from `kendo-data-query` - The `groupBy` itself works but the list displays empty (ie: no items) even though there're no errors.

this is my component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header-channels',
    templateUrl: './header-channels.component.html'
})
export class HeaderChannelsComponent {
    public listItems: Array<{ text: string, value: number, type: string }> = [
        { text: '4 Cantos', value: 1, type: 'Operators' },
        { text: 'CVC', value: 2, type: 'Operators' },
        { text: 'Channel 3', value: 3, type: 'Agencies' }
    ];

    public selectedItem: { text: string, value: number, type: string } = this.listItems[1];

    public data;

    constructor() {
        this.data = groupBy(this.listItems.slice(), [{ field: 'type' }]);
    }

    handleFilter(value) {
        this.data = groupBy(this.listItems.filter((s) => s.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1), [{ field: 'type' }]);
    }
}
```

and this is my component's template:

```html
<kendo-dropdownlist
    [data]="data"
    [filterable]="true"
    [textField]="'text'"
    [valueField]="'value'"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
    (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

I'm breaking my head over this...

Comment: As far as I know the Kendo DropDownList for Angular doesn't support grouped data. It can render only flat lists of data. The best think will be to post your idea here - http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback

Comment: yes, your right, I've been looking arround for a solution for this and the documentation states that "The data has to be provided in an array-like list." I'll follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I've been investigating this a lot and found out that at the time being it's not possible to group the data that will be displayed in a `kendo-dropdownlist`. The [kendo Ui for Angular Docs](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownListComponent/#toc-data) state that "The data has to be provided in an array-like list.".

For now I've managed to work arround this using `kendoDropDownListItemTemplate` to achieve the disired result (visualy).

I've added a 'first' `boolean` `property` to the objects in my array as:

```
public listItems: Array<{ text: string, value: number, type: string, first?: boolean }> = [
  { text: '4 Cantos', value: 1, type: 'Operators', first: true },
  { text: 'CVC', value: 2, type: 'Operators' },
  { text: 'Operator 3', value: 2, type: 'Operators' },
  { text: 'Operator 4', value: 2, type: 'Operators' },
  { text: 'Channel 3', value: 3, type: 'Agencies', first: true },
  { text: 'Another Agency', value: 3, type: 'Agencies' }
];
```

And then in my template file I'll check this and display the group title accordingly:

```
<ng-template kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem>
  <span class="test-item">
    {{dataItem.text}}
    <span class="k-group test" *ngIf="dataItem.first">{{ dataItem.type }}</span>
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

And styles for the purpose  (of course):

```
.test-item{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
.test-item > .k-group {
    font-size: 10px;

    background: #ebebeb;
    color: #3f51b5;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    line-height: 1.8;
}
```

And I achieve my desired visual aspect:[image]

**The problem with this workarround** is that the objects inside of the array have to be correctly sorted and organized prior to defining it as the dropdownList data, making sure that the `first` item of a `type` always comes first and followed by all the other items inside the same `type`.